# Roll back from Marlin 2.0 to manufacturer closed-source firmware

Tags: marlin, diy-3d-printer, firmware, software

Because I needed to insert nuts in my prints and therefore G-code instructions in their file, I upgraded my printer firmware to Marlin as in here :

At the beginning I did used to get the 6 beeps when booting, and was able to boot back to the initial firmware when hiding the `upgrade.cbd` file in a folder, instead of the root level of the SD card.

But I did by mistake load/save some settings to the EEPROM I guess, and I cannot get back to the initial firmware - at boot time there isn't any beep anymore and it boots directly on the marlin boot wallpaper.

How to prevent Marlin forcing the 3D printer to boot on it please?

Comment: Note that you probably never had to upgrade to Marlin 2.0, you could have inserted a pause or at least a dwell command in your older firmware.

Comment: I tried this https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/cant-manage-to-force-my-print-to-standby-while-i-insert-a-nut-prusa-slicer-an , what is a dwell command please? Also I needed to modify the nozzle to prober offset because the stock fan duct was bumping into the prints and idk if it's feasible on chitu boards

Comment: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/cant-manage-to-force-my-print-to-standby-while-i-insert-a-nut-prusa-slicer-an#comment25520_14191 see also [G4: Dwell](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G4:_Dwell)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it as soon as I get back to my initial UI !

Comment: Tried this https://www.tronxyonline.com/Firmware-XY-Series-a63177.html but after launching the gcode print and restarting, Marlin persists...

Comment: what did you do to actually get to the problem in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure to remember but I think I miss-pressed `store settings` in the `motion>bed-leveling` touchscreen UI